# Modify Arrow Key Navigation to support Mobile Swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I currently use the code below to navigate to the next and previous pages by allowing the user to use the left and right buttons.  How would I integrate the code for swiping on the mobile phone for navigation?

```
    var browser = navigator.appName;
    if (browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        document.onkeydown=keydownie;
    } else {
        document.onkeydown=keydown;
    }
    function keydownie(e) {
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        if (e.keyCode) {
            keycode = e.keyCode;
            if ((keycode == 39) || (keycode == 37)) {
                window.event.keyCode = 0;
            }
        } else {
            keycode = e.which;
        }
        if (keycode == 37) {
            img = document.querySelector("img[src='http://www.example.com/arrowleft.jpg'],img[src='http://www.example.com/images/left.png']");
            window.location = img.parentElement.href;
            return false;
        } else if (keycode == 39) {
            img = document.querySelector("img[src='http://www.example.com/arrowright.jpg'],img[src='http://www.example.com/images/right.png']");
            window.location = img.parentElement.href;
            return false;
        }
    }
    function keydown(e) {
        if (e.which) {
            keycode = e.which;
        } else {
            keycode = e.keyCode;
        }
        if (keycode == 37) {
            img = document.querySelector("img[src='http://www.example.com/arrowleft.jpg'],img[src='http://www.example.com/images/left.png']");
            window.location = img.parentElement.href;
            return false;
        } else if (keycode == 39) {
            img = document.querySelector("img[src='http://www.example.com/arrowright.jpg'],img[src='http://www.example.com/images/right.png']");
            window.location = img.parentElement.href;
            return false;
        }
    }
```